# multiple firefox installations (+ profile) still execute always latest version

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, selenium

I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring out why i am not able to run a different versions of Firefox.

I downloaded versions 10 and 14 to do some testing and i also have my default installation from Ubuntu's official repo (which is now at version 17).

I have created separate profiles for the different installations (ffx10, ffx14).

When i try to run the command:

```
firefox-14/firefox-bin -P ffx14
```

I still get firefox 17...

p.s. cannot post screenshot... but here's a link to one :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3c2f.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox now performs auto updates, so check if that is disabled, or else all previous versions will get autoupdated to FF17.

Comment: That was it indeed... deleted instalation and re-installed, disabled automatic updates as described in https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/753852 and now i can run the other versions. Thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem, i faced the exact issue it took me hours to figure out.

Comment: as an aditional note, the auto update setting can be found in prefs.js inside the profile directory. On mine i see:  

    user_pref("app.update.auto", false);
    user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);